# Converting wmv video file to mp4 video file using MediaMuxer and MediaCodec

Tags: android, media, android-mediacodec, mediamuxer

I want to convert .wmv video file to mp4 video file. Is possible to using [MediaMuxer](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaMuxer.html) and [MediaCodec](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaCodec.html) classes?

Comment: Please see this... I need your help... [MP4ParserMergeAudioVideo][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30230709/no-audio-in-mp4-file-android

Answer (score 1):

MediaMuxer is used to create .mp4 files.  It is not a format converter.

If you have a way to decode .wmv into video frames and a PCM audio stream, then you can feed that data to MediaCodec encoders, and direct that into MediaMuxer to construct an output file.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.
Can you suggest me a solution to decode .wmv video file?

Comment: I don't have one to recommend.