# No audio in MP4 file - Android

Tags: java, android, audio, mp4parser

I am using the [MP4ParserMergeAudioVideo](https://github.com/tqnst/MP4ParserMergeAudioVideo/tree/master/Mp4ParserSample-master) to add a new audio to an `MP4` file. The library had said to use `.wav` file, if i keep a `.wav` file in the directory and give the name of the audiofile as `example.m4a`, I get a file not found exception. So I changed the file to a `.m4a` audio file. The code is given below.

```
findViewById(R.id.append).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        String root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
        Log.e("",""+root);
        String audio = root + "/download/"+"mymovieaudio.m4a";
        String video = root + "/download/"+"My_Movie.mp4";
        String output = root + "/download/ouput.mp4";
        mux(video, audio, output);
    }
});
```

The mux function is like this

```
public boolean mux(String videoFile, String audioFile, String outputFile) {
        Movie video;
        try {
            video = new MovieCreator().build(videoFile);
        } catch (RuntimeException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }

        Movie audio;
        try {
            audio = new MovieCreator().build(audioFile);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }

        Track audioTrack = audio.getTracks().get(0);
        video.addTrack(audioTrack);

        Container out = new DefaultMp4Builder().build(video);

        FileOutputStream fos;
        try {
            fos = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }
        BufferedWritableFileByteChannel byteBufferByteChannel = new BufferedWritableFileByteChannel(fos);
        try {
            out.writeContainer(byteBufferByteChannel);
            byteBufferByteChannel.close();
            fos.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

I successfully get the `output.mp4` file in my download directory of my device. The problem is that it does not have any audio. Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you have to ask this problem at MP4ParserMergeAudioVideo github.